# Add custom user meta data

Tags: users, user-meta

I want to add a custom meta data for all the users with a default false value. I have researched about adding a meta data i.e, `add_user_meta( int $user_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, bool $unique = false )` which allows only adding a meta data to a particular user. But I want to add it for all the users.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Adding custom field to all existing users.

You will have to get the list of users and then, in a loop, set a custom field for each of them.

```
$users = get_users( [
    'fields' => 'id', 
    'meta_key' => 'YOUR_META_KEY', 
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
] );
if ( is_array($users) && count($users) )
{
    $meta_value = false;
    foreach( $users as $user_id ) {
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'YOUR_META_KEY', $meta_value, true);
    }
}
```

The version with a single query requires the use of an SQL query. The function will return FALSE in case of error.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->usermeta} (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) "
    . "SELECT ID, 'YOUR_META_KEY', '' FROM {$wpdb->users} u "
    . " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} um ON um.user_id = u.ID AND um.meta_key='YOUR_META_KEY' "
    . " WHERE um.umeta_id IS NULL";
$result = $wpdb->query( $sql_query );
```

Above code should be run once.

**Example**:
*functions.php*

```
add_action( 'init', 'se338136_add_meta_to_existing_users' );
function se338136_add_meta_to_existing_users() {
    $option_meta_name = '_my_meta_added';
    $executed = get_option( $option_meta_name, false );
    if ( $executed == 1 )
        return;

    // here one of the above codes

    // if ($result !== false )
    update_option( $option_meta_name, 1 );
}
```

### Adding a custom field when adding a new user.

```
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', 'new_user_meta', 20, 3);

/**
 * @param array   $meta   Default meta values and keys for the user.
 * @param WP_User $user   User object.
 * @param bool    $update Whether the user is being updated rather than created.
 */
function new_user_meta( $meta, $user, $update ) 
{
    if ( $update )
        return $meta;

    $meta['YOUR_META_KEY'] = false;
    return $meta;
}
```

---

**References**:

- [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [$wpdb->query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries)
- [insert_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/insert_user_meta/)

Comment: Hi, how can i add the user meta for a newly created user. Will this code work for all the users if they are new created also?

Comment: This is the code for a single run, add a metadata for all existing users, then it should be removed. That's how I understood: `I want to add it for all the users.`. To add a custom field when creating a new user, use the [`insert_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/insert_user_meta/) filter hook.

Comment: Thats's great. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @Subham I added a variant for creating a new user with a custom field

Comment: So, if i add this code alone it should work right?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use it. You can add it to the `functions.php` file to the `init` action hook, then open the website in your browser so that the code will be executed and after all comment or delete it. You can also add a button in the administration and execute the code on demand via [`admin_post_ {action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_\(action\)).

Comment: Will it add the meta data for all existing users. I have 2 existing users. I want to add meta data to them as well as users who will be created here after.

Comment: Add code for both cases.  `get_option( )` will make sure that the operation for existing users will be done once. `add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', 'new_user_meta', 20, 3);` will add custom field to each new user when creating it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to do this in SQL, so I did it in phpMyAdmin without writing any PHP code